# I ran makemigrations and migrate but my columns are not reflecting in PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm new to Django, my version is 4.1. I had issues changing the field type of the id column in pgAdmin4. But I overrode the ID by making migrations with id in midel.uuidfield like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
import uuid


class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    # id = None 
    id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=True,      verbose_name='ID')
    password = None
```

This worked at last when I ran makegrations and changed the id from None to models.uuidfield before migrating. Now this column and every other column added is not reflecting in the database, that is the PgAdmin4.

I tried to troubleshoot by adding a new column, `created_time`, like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
import uuid


class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    # id = None 
    id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID')
    password = None
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now after running makemigrations and migrate, the only record that got added to the database was the `created_time`. So i checked the migrations folder and in my `0001_initial.py file`, it looks like this:

```
# Generated by Django 4.1.7 on 2023-04-04 07:11

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Profile',
            fields=[
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('id', models.UUIDField(editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, unique=True, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('firstname', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name='the first name of a user')),
                ('lastname', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name='the last name of a user')),
                ('display_pic', models.ImageField(blank=True, default='images/avatar.jpg', null=True, upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d', verbose_name='profile picture')),
                ('username', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name='username')),
                ('email', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name='email')),
                ('bio', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='bio of user')),
                ('is_email_verified', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="this designates if the user' email is verified")),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='this designates if the user is active')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='this designates if the user is staff or not')),
            ],
            options={
                'unique_together': {('id', 'email', 'username')},
            },
        ),
    ]
```

but after I added the created_time field, the new migration file is like this:

```
# Generated by Django 4.1.7 on 2023-04-04 07:19

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('subscribers', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='created_time',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

It's clear that the initial migrations did not apply any changes.

Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: Is there a chance that you created initial migration without UUID field, run `migrate`, deleted initial migration without reverting migration in db, added UUID field, run `makemgirations` and `migrate`? If yes then Django sees 0001_initial as done migration and it doesn't check if migration file changed

Comment: I've deleted all initial files yet it still isn't creating tables. @PTomasz

Comment: I also think it's what @PTomasz said.  In this case, before deleting the already applied migration, you need to reverse that migration first.  Once it's reversed, you can delete the migration file, recreate it, and do a forward migration again.

Answer (score 0):

I have an update. So I found out that the only solution that worked, was to delete the entire database or create a new one and connect it in Django `settings.py` file. Then I made all the modifications to the id and every other field.
I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` and now the tables are reflecting.

I hope this helps someone else